# How to Make Text Box Control Resizable in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to modify an add-on for excel which takes data from each cell of the worksheet and puts it into text boxes where the information can more readily be read and modified.

Since some cells contain a great deal of text (and the text boxes are by default only large enough for one line), I am attempting to make the text boxes adjustable so that the user is able to see all the text in the cell.

The below link is a picture so you know exactly what I mean:

http://www.jibberjobber.com/blog/wp-content/chrome_resize_text_boxes.png

Please understand that I **do not want** the form to simply be enlarged to a specific size, as that is easy to accomplish, but I would prefer to allow the user to choose the size that best fits the amount of text, size, and font.

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: You can't have that without anchoring the edges of the textbox and resizing the *form* you put the box in. VBA controls aren't web UI controls.

Comment: The form is resizable. Do you mean that I can only resize the text boxes by resizing the entire form?

Comment: Yes. Well by user drag-and-drop action anyway, as far as I know. You could have a little +/- button somewhere to programmatically increase/decrease the height of the textbox, but that would quickly and inevitably turn into a layout nightmare IMO.

Comment: Agreed. I understand that web and VBA controls are different, but does that mean there is not an option besides anchoring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different approach. Change in run time the textbox settings. In this case

```
Private Sub TextBox2_Enter()
    showTextbox2Text
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    returnOriginalTextbox2Text
End Sub

Sub showTextbox2Text()
    TextBox3.Visible = False
    TextBox2.MultiLine = True
    TextBox2.Height = 75 'make some calculation to adapt to your with and text in textbox
End Sub

Sub returnOriginalTextbox2Text()
    TextBox3.Visible = Visible 'original setting
    TextBox2.MultiLine = False 'original setting
    TextBox2.Height = 25 'original setting
End Sub
```

Before enter TextBox2
[image: Before enter TextBox2]

After enter Textbox2 ... in exit will return to the original
[image: Enter TextBox2]

Answer (score 0):

You want the user to see and edit the information in a better way? 
You could make a trick ... that is open a new form with the information in the original text box now in a bigger textbox. This form could be generic to be used in all text box and could be called by a button.

[image: OriginalForm]
[image: EditForm]

Comment: Interesting idea. But how can I make that text box fit the text I am using?

Answer (score 0):

following your ***original*** question, i.e.:

"*...I would prefer to allow the user to choose the size that best fits the amount of text, size, and font*"

you can place the following code in your userform code pane:

```
Option Explicit

Private mouseLeft As Single, mouseTop As Single

Private Sub TextBox1_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single) '<~~ change "TextBox1" to whatever the actual name of your textbox
    If Button = 1 Then
        mouseLeft = X
        mouseTop = Y
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single) '<~~ change "TextBox1" to whatever the actual name of your textbox
    If Button = 1 Then
        With Me.TextBox1 '<~~ change "TextBox1" to whatever the actual name of your textbox
            .Width = .Width + X - mouseLeft
            .Height = .Height + Y - mouseTop
        End With
        mouseLeft = X
        mouseTop = Y
    End If
End Sub
```

and the user can drag textbox borders to desired sizes